# JSON post request shows 405 not allowed error (using XMLHttpRequest())

Tags: javascript, json, post, get, xmlhttprequest

here's my js code:

```
 var myreq=new XMLHttpRequest();
myreq.open("GET","https://<username>.github.io/test/data/data.json",true);
myreq.onload =function(){
  console.log(JSON.parse(myreq.response));
}
myreq.send();
const data={
    "name": "jayant",
    "job": "leader"
};
 function here()
 {
  var myreq1=new XMLHttpRequest();
    myreq1.onload = () => {

        // print JSON response
        if (myreq1.status >= 200 && myreq1.status < 300) {
            // parse JSON
            const response = JSON.parse(myreq1.responseText);
            console.log(response);
        }
    };
  myreq1.open("POST",'https://<username>.github.io/test/data/data.json');
  myreq1.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  myreq1.send(JSON.stringify(data)); 
 }
```

Function here is called on a button click
and here's my JSON code:

```
[
    {
        "name1":"jayant",
        "age":58,
        "pass":"LetsLearnJson"
    },
    {
        "name1":"jayant2",
        "age":45,
        "pass":"ok"
    },
    {
        "name1":"jayant3",
        "age":24,
        "pass":"test"
    },
    {
        "name1":"abcd",
        "age":75,
        "pass":"abcd"
    }
]
```

I am getting this error when I try to post:

```
POST https://<username>.github.io/test/%22https://<username>.github.io/test/data/data.json%22 405
```

Please help. I have tried many things already available online but nothing seems to work

Comment: XMLHttpRequest is a legacy API you should try to use the Fetch api. [Link to fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

Comment: @SebastianCiocarlan - using fetch won't fix the issue

Comment: @JaromandaX true I've should have specified that as well in the comment.

Comment: meh @SebastianCiocarlan I think people who still use XHR probably would get scared off by the whole "promises" thing :

Answer (score -1):

The 405 Method Not Allowed Error occurs when the web server is configured so that you cannot perform a specific action for a specific URL. It is an HTTP response status code that indicates that the request method is known to the server, but is not supported by the target resource.